# Rails 4 nested fields not displayed in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I am trying to display nested some user.profile nested fields in a signup form (first_name, last_name)  , but they don't appear ..

```
    == CONTROLLER
    controllers/users_controller.rb
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def new
        @user = User.new
        render partial: 'users/new_form_content', layout: false 
      end

      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password,  profile_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name])
      end
     ...
    end

    == MODELS
    models/user.rb
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_one :profile
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

    end
    class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
    end

    == VIEW
    users/new_form_content.rb
    <div>
    ...
    <%= form_for @user, remote: true, ... do |f| %>

        <%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile_form| %>
            <%= profile_form.text_field :last_name %>
            <%= profile_form.text_field :first_name %>
        <% end %>
        ...

        <%= f.text_field :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :password %>
        <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation %>
        ...

    <% end %>
    ...
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new profile in your new method as well:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.profile = Profile.new
    render partial: 'users/new_form_content', layout: false 
  end
```

Comment: Yeah, caused me some headache a while back too.